# Meteor & Iron Router {{> yield}} not pulling template in

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

EDIT: I ran ***meteor add ejson*** and that fixed it.

I'm loosely following Discover Meteor to build my own application. I just implemented iron router, and now my template is not pulling in the data. I checked the DB and the data is sitting there. The answer is probably obvious, but I have been through the code a 100 times and can't figure it out. If I change {{> yield}} back to {{> dealsList}} it works fine.

Layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{pathFor 'dealsList'}}">swigFU</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Router.js

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'dealsList'});
```

deals_list.html

```
<template name="dealsList">
  <div class="posts page">
    {{#each deals}}
      {{> dealItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I also get this error in the browser console which seems like it may have something to do with it, but I don't understand what I'm looking at.

```
Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined
    at MiddlewareStack.concat (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:303:25)
    at RouteController._runRoute (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:542:17)
    at Function.Route.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:856:18)
    at route (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:713:11)
    at boundNext (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:425:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?637cc835a2ee4a2302a010c9a4c97b906db5f41c:1007:22
    at dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:449:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:393:13
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?16c53d4f91467c6a41bbb860bf6c48f871710022:357:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?16c53d4f91467c6a41bbb860bf6c48f871710022:245:10)
```

Comment: You have to execute this in your console: meteor add ejson. Look at this: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1438

Comment: Thanks man, yeah, I figured that out after pulling my hair out for a few hours.

Comment: Did you find my comment useful? In that case could you mark it? Thanks!!